# Cant pick out parameters from this wsdl to use in webservice call

Tags: android, wsdl, ksoap2

I need to call the following webservice and I have its corresponding WSDL file. However I cannot get the below code to work.

```
<wsdl:definitions name="ServiceTestService" targetNamespace="http://Rothman.com/">
<wsdl:types>
<schema>
<import namespace="http://Rothman.com/" schemaLocation="http://Rothmanweb.cloudfoundry.com/services/ServiceTestPort?xsd=servicetest_schema1.xsd"/>
</schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="WhatIsTheAnswerResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:WhatIsTheAnswerResponse" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="WhatIsTheAnswer">
   <wsdl:part element="tns:WhatIsTheAnswer" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="QuestionSEI">
  <wsdl:operation name="WhatIsTheAnswer">
          <wsdl:input message="tns:WhatIsTheAnswer" name="WhatIsTheAnswer"> </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output message="tns:WhatIsTheAnswerResponse" name="WhatIsTheAnswerResponse"></wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="ServiceTestServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:QuestionSEI">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="WhatIsTheAnswer">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="WhatIsTheAnswer">
  <soap:body use="literal"/>
 </wsdl:input>
 <wsdl:output name="WhatIsTheAnswerResponse"><soap:body use="literal"/>
 </wsdl:output>
 </wsdl:operation>
 </wsdl:binding>
 <wsdl:service name="ServiceTestService">
     <wsdl:port binding="tns:ServiceTestServiceSoapBinding" name="ServiceTestPort">
     <soap:address location="http://Rothmanweb.cloudfoundry.com/services/ServiceTestPort"/>
     </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Now I have the following code but I cant seem to find the parameters from the WSDL to connect to this service. The sercvice takes a string as an input and returns a string as an output.
I have the following code fragment and I am not sure about the following final static values.

```
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://Rothman.com/"; //ok
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "WhatIsTheAnswer"; //ok

private static final String URL = "http://Rothmanweb.cloudfoundry.com/services/ServiceTestPort?wsdl";   
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://Rothman.com/WhatIsTheAnswer";
```

These values are used as follows

```
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);        
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope =  new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransport(URL);
    try 
    {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        System.out.println("Received object");
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me how I could use this code to get a response from this webservice. Are my final variables correct ? The service properly works since I tested it using soapUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL with **WSDL** must be real accesible address from android device. And also imported **XSD** schema in **WSDL**  must be accesible.

If your web service requires input string, you must specify `PropertyInfo` as an input param.

```
PropertyInfo methodParam = new PropertyInfo();
methodParam.setName("string");
methodParam.setValue(yourString);
methodParam.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
Request.addProperty(methodParam);


SoapObject soapObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, methodName);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);
```

Comment: Isn't it suppose to be `soapObject.addProperty(methodParam)` . I believe you have a typo

Comment: I'm sorry. there should be `Request.addProperty(methodParam);`. Take a look on this tutorial http://seesharpgears.blogspot.sk/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html